# Python search for a string and print the next x number of lines

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am trying to figure out how to send a shell command, search for a string in a line, and print x number of lines. I am able to accomplish this if I use open to read the file but having difficulty doing it via the shell. I'd like to be able to send a shell command and use the similar grep -A command. Is there a Pythonic way to do this? Below is my testable code. Thanks in advance.

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

# Works when I use open to read the file:

with open("test_file.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for items in myfile:
        if 'Cherry' in items.strip():
            for index in range(5):
               line = next(myfile)
               print (line.strip())

# Fails when I try to send the command through the shell

command = (subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'test_file.txt'], shell=False).decode('utf-8').splitlines())
for items in command:
    if 'Cherry' in items.strip():
        for index in range(5):
            line = next(command)
```

Output with Error:

```
Dragonfruit

--- Fruits ---
Artichoke
Arugula

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/next_line.py", line 26, in <module>
    line = next(command)
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Contents of test_file.txt:

```
--- Fruits ---
Apple
Banana
Blueberry
Cherry
Dragonfruit

--- Fruits ---
Artichoke
Arugula
Asparagus
Broccoli
Cabbage
```

Comment: You've wrapped a list inside of a generator. Remove the extraneous parens around the `subprocess.check_output` line. (This takes the list returned by `check_output` and wraps it inside of a generator, which... isn't what you want, I'm sure, haha.)

Comment: @PierceDarragh I don't think it does. You'd need a generator expression for that.

Comment: @Pierce Darragh, removing the parenthesis did not help. It's still evaluating as a list with the same error.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh actually it returns the same thing either way, it turns out. Which make sense actually, since there's no `for` to trigger the generator comprehension. So they're just superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the iterator yourself instead of letting `for` do it for you... (may or may not work, I didn't exactly test this)

```
command = (subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'test_file.txt'], shell=False).decode('utf-8').splitlines())
iterator = iter(command)
for items in iterator:
    if 'Cherry' in items.strip():
        for index in range(5):
            line = next(iterator)
```

Comment: This didn't quite do it either. I am getting an empty output.

Comment: I missed the print statement! This worked great. Thank you.

Comment: @MBasith sorry, I probably could have inferred you would have a print statement and put it in.. glad I could help